# setInterval & setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to stop my javascript after x seconds, I saw that the function is setTimeout, I tried to add that to my code but no succes, is this the better way to do this?
Thanks for your help !

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function blink(){
state = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.visibility;
if(state == 'hidden'){
    newState = 'visible';
}else if(state == 'visible'){
    newState = 'hidden';
}
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.visibility = newState;
    }
   setInterval('blink();', 300);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2011/10/12/8875514/star_white.jpg" style="visibility:hidden">  
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your interval in a variable and clear it after `X` (here 2) seconds:

```
var interval = setInterval(blink, 300);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
var myvar;

function myStartFunction()
{
    myvar=setInterval(function(){blink()},300);
}
function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myvar);
}
```